# 12.04 won't install from disk

Tags: installation, 12.04

I am trying to install ubuntu from the disk which I burned the 12.04 image to. So I went into the BIOS and disabled boot from everything except cd-rom, and it said there was no bootable partition. And on another PC it said "boot device and press enter".

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem. How did you burn the iso? By simply writing it to the cd using some cd burning application? If so, the boot loader might not have been installed. Try using a pen drive and make it bootable using the "Startup disk creator" utility.

Comment: i burned to a dvd with infra recorder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling everything else, just put CD at the top level.

Comment: i tried that too

Comment: i just got done trying it from a usb stick andit didnt work. also when i try it from wubi it just gives me a really wierd message with lots and LOTS of question marks. if theres anything im doing wrong pls tell me

Comment: Do you have another computer with ubuntu? if so try burning the iso using basero (i think thats the spelling).

Answer (score 0):

How did you burn your CD? Is it possible that you simply copied the ISO over as a data file, rather than burn the CD using the ISO as the image?

Comment: nope. i used infra recorder and i specifically remember picking burn image

Comment: Since it has failed multiple times, and it sounds like you've tested on multiple PCs, the only other thing I can think of is to double-check that you downloaded the correct ISO.  If it is the correct version, while it seems highly unlikely, the ISO may be corrupted in some way and you may want to download a new version.

Answer (score 0):

If every thing fails on this computer, use another computer, put that hard drive in there, install like normal to that hard drive and after successful installation put the hard drive back into the computer that refuses to boot from CD and USB stick.

Usually booting and installing from USB stick works without a flaw.

Have you chosen the right Ubuntu edition for the installed CPU? What computer model is this? What mainboard and BIOS does it have? Is it a new machine that uses uEFI instead if BIOS?